# Visual Studio no reconoce el lenguaje que utilizo en los archivos

Tags: python

Soy nuevo programando, y uso el VS Code para programar en python (mi primer lenguaje) y cada vez que creaba un archivo nuevo para empezar una lección nuevo o miniproyecto siempre reconocía que estaba creando un archivo .py
Ahora ya no lo hace y tampoco con el nuevo lenguaje que estoy aprendiendo (C++) y ya instalé los paquetes y todo está en orden para mí. ¿Alguna solución?
He intentado desinstalarlo y vovlerlo a instalar, busqué tutoriales sin éxito :(